# How do I get Grunt to recompile dependent SASS files?

Tags: sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-sass

I'm trying to work my way through the updates to Visual Studio 2015 including using Grunt and so on.

I can get Grunt to recompile `.scss` files when they change, but I have a problem. I use SASS for theming, and a lot of my CSS is in a central `_main.scss`. What I want is when I edit that file, it should recompile all the `theme-*.scss` files that include `_main.scss`.

Is there any way to tell `watch` or stuff like that to recompile things when dependencies change? Even if I have to specify the dependencies manually?

Comment: why not recompile everything, dirty and costly it must be!

Comment: Well, it's slow. I have some Bootstrap themes defined as well as project themes. Modifying the `scss` for the project themes shouldn't require the Bootstrap themes to get recompiled. On a fast computer it takes about 30 seconds to compile all the CSS. Meanwhile, Web Essentials used to compile just the dependencies in like 3 seconds.

Comment: In regards to the slow compile time compared to Web Essentials.  Are you compiling with LibSass?  If not switching to that over the Ruby based version will drastically improve compile times

Comment: Thanks, Colin! I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to follow dependencies from one file to another, but you can watch for changes in `.scss` files and then run a sass task to update your theme files.

So you'll have your sass task like this:

```
    sass : {
        build: {
            files : {
                'path/to/compiled-foo.css': 'path/to/theme-foo.scss',
                'path/to/compiled-bar.css': 'path/to/theme-bar.scss',
                // Or more generally
                'path/to': 'path/to/theme-*.scss',
            }
        }
    },
```

And then your watch task like this:

```
    watch : {
        themes: {
            files : [ 'path/to/_main.scss' ],
            tasks : [ 'sass' ],
            options : {
                // You may change these to better suit your needs
                spawn : false,
                interrupt: true,
                livereload: true
            },
        },
    },
```

The downside of this is that all your themes will compile each time you change your `_main.scss`. If you have different files to watch for different themes then you can have more tasks inside `watch` (instead of `themes` you can make `theme_foo` and `theme_bar` call different tasks (e.g.: `sass:theme_foo` or `sass:theme_bar`) and then recompile just that theme.

You can also run `grunt watch` on a specific task: `grunt watch theme_foo`, which won't update `theme_bar` but just `theme_foo`.

---

**Edit**: You can modularize your `_main.scss` so it becomes `_foo.scss`, `_bar.scss` and `_common.scss`, and then change `_common.scss` when it's a change that affects all themes, and `_foo.scss` when it just affects `theme_foo`. This way you can monitor `_foo.scss` and update only `theme_foo` when it changes; or update all your themes just when `_common.scss` changes.

---

**Edit 2** (based on comments):
Lets say we have two themes, **blue** and **red**. We'll have two sass tasks (one for each theme):

```
    sass : {
        red: {
            files : {
                'path/to/compiled-red.css': 'path/to/theme-red.scss',
            }
        },
        blue: {
            files : {
                'path/to/compiled-blue.css': 'path/to/theme-blue.scss',
            }
        },
    },
```

Right now, if you run `grunt sass` it will update both themes. But if you run `grunt sass red` it will update just the red theme.

To make your `watch` update just the required theme, you'll have two tasks:

```
    watch : {
        red: {
            files : [ 'path/to/theme-red.scss' ],
            tasks : [ 'sass:red' ],
            options : { /* ... */ },
        },

        blue: {
            files : [ 'path/to/theme-blue.scss' ],
            tasks : [ 'sass:blue' ],
            options : { /* ... */ },
        },
    },
```

Notice `red` calls `sass:red` (the task for that theme and only that theme). Same happens with `blue` calling `sass:blue`.

To make it update every theme when `_main.scss` changes, you add one more task inside `watch`:

```
    watch : {
        red: {
            files : [ 'path/to/theme-red.scss' ],
            tasks : [ 'sass:red' ],
            options : { /* ... */ },
        },

        blue: {
            files : [ 'path/to/theme-blue.scss' ],
            tasks : [ 'sass:blue' ],
            options : { /* ... */ },
        },

        all: {
            files : [ 'path/to/_main.scss' ],
            tasks : [ 'sass' ],
            options : { /* ... */ },
        },
    },
```

Now `all` is watching your `_main.scss`, and when it changes every task in `sass` will be run (i.e. `sass:red` and `sass:blue`).

Comment: It's already modularized. `_main.scss` has things that affect all themes. `theme-red.scss` then is basically `$brand: #ff0000; include "_main";`. So updating `_main.scss` should recompile all theme files, while updating `theme-red.scss` should only update `theme-red.css`.

Comment: @AnthonyMills Perfect then! You can watch `_main.scss` and make it update every theme (you can have a sass task which updates every theme), while you can also watch `theme-red.scss` and make it update just the red theme (calling sass task `red`). I just updated my answer to show this.